# Why does the youtube video force close the app when played?

Tags: android, video, youtube, crash

I have a hybrid app with a random youtube video placed in an iframe it runs smoothly util i click on the video to play it. Once i click on the video the buffering logo comes up and i hear a small amount of sound that sounds laggy and then the app closes down. I dont understand why this is happening i have shown the errors in the logcat below

Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initWebView();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        WebView.class.getMethod("onResume").invoke(mWebView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        WebView.class.getMethod("onPause").invoke(mWebView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void initWebView() {
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    // WebViewの設定
    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);


    String html = "";
    html += "<html><body>";
    html += "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/MU9Srs04sFU?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    html += "</body></html>";

    mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
}
}
```

LOGCAT

```
09-28 10:01:59.005    1196-1255/com.fly1tkg.youtube_webview E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
09-28 10:02:00.471    1196-1255/com.fly1tkg.youtube_webview A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 1255 (RenderThread)
```

Comment: are you using an emulator?

Comment: @PrasanthLouis i am is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the  "Use host GPU" setting checked on your emulator, it'll cause this error. To fix it, just remove the tick from the option

Use a phone for testing instead. By not using this option (use host gpu), your emulator won't be very responsive.